# What replaces Configuration Application Block(of 1.0) in Enterprise Library 4.0 or 4.1?

Tags: configuration, enterprise-library

I remember using Configuration Application Block in Enterprise Library 1.0.

What is the equivalent of it in 4.0 or 4.1 version?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no equivalent. When .NET 2.0 Framework came out, the Configuration Application Block has been deprecated in favor of System.Configuration.

On a separate note, are there any configuration scenarios that you feel you need help with, similarly to what Configuration Application Block offerred?